# run executable on boot

Tags: debian, startup, raspberry-pi

For the life of me, I cannot get this to work. I'm running Debian on Raspberry Pi.

running this command from CLI:

```
/home/pi/domotiga/DomotiGaServer.gambas -d
```

runs my home automation server.

How do I go about running this on boot?

I have a file in my /etc/init.d dir that does get loaded, but it doesn't launch the server

file contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          domotigaserver
# Required-Start:    $syslog $mysql
# Required-Stop:     $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: domotiga server
# Description:
#
### END INIT INFO

#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/domotigaserver
#

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
start)
su pi -c '/home/pi/domotiga/DomotiGaServer.gambas -d'
echo "Starting DomotiGa Server " 
;;
stop)
pkill DomotiGaServer.gambas
echo "DomotiGa Server has been stopped (didn't double check though)" 
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/domotigaserver {start|stop}" 
exit 1
;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Writing the init.d script is not enough, you need to create start/stop links in /etc/rc[0-9].d for the proper run level. Tools like rcconf or update-rc.d can do this for you. See e.g. http://www.debianadmin.com/manage-linux-init-or-startup-scripts.html

Comment: @jofel A verbose version of that comment would make an excellent answer.

Comment: rcconf reports that the domotigaserver is scheduled to load - is that enough? When watching the startup text, 'domotigaserver started' is also listed, yet the server isn't running. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeThrussell If you see the message, your script seems to be called. Does the program start if you call your script by hand?

Comment: @jofel yes, it starts when called by hand - I log in (ssh) as user 'pi' to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the script was executing too early; before some prerequisites. Symlinks were named S03domotigaserver - I renamed them to S80domotigaserver and it now works.

Answer (score 3):

Creating init.d scripts is not enough. You need
to create start/stop links in `/etc/rc[0-9].d` for the proper [run level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).

By default, Debian uses run level 2 (configurable in `/etc/inittab`).

To create appropriate links, you can use [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).
Run

```
update-rc.d domotigaserver defaults
```

as root user.

Alternatively, you can use `rcconf` (install it e.g. by `apt-get install rcconf`). It offers a nice [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

See for example [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/manage-linux-init-or-startup-scripts.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be my problem. Running '/etc/init.d/domotigaserver start' by hand also starts the server ok, and rcconf reports it is set to run on startup and the script executes, but the server isn't loaded.